# play video before redirecting to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use a video as a background that automatically stretches to the whole screen,in such a way that if a page is loaded then just before the loading of the content a video plays for 5 sec then it pauses and contents are loaded and again start playing if user clicks on another link,and the user will not be redirected before the video finishes.

```
 $(function() {
var BV = new $.BigVideo();
BV.init();
BV.show('http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4');
});
```

my code is working fine its just that I don't know how to play the video just before redirecting to another page without using an intermediate page

Comment: As a user this sounds *really* annoying. Have a Google for the `onBeforeUnload` event. That will do what you need.

Comment: The `onbeforeunload` event won't be able to keep the user on the page though. For this, you'd have to rewrite every link on the page to play the video, and go to the link's location after that. It would break if the user opens the link in a new window, though, and some types of links (Javascript events) would be very hard to rewrite. This will be a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function vidplay() {
   var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
   var button = document.getElementById("play");
   if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
      button.textContent = "||";
   } else {
      video.pause();
      button.textContent = ">";
   }
}

function restart() {
    var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
    video.currentTime = 0;
}

function skip(value) {
    var video = document.getElementById("Video1");
    video.currentTime += value;
}      
</script>

</head>
<body>        

<video id="Video1" >
//  Replace these with your own video files. 
 <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
 <source src="demo.ogv" type="video/ogg" />
 HTML5 Video is required for this example. 
 <a href="demo.mp4">Download the video</a> file. 
</video>

<div id="buttonbar">
<button id="restart" onclick="restart();">[]</button> 
<button id="rew" onclick="skip(-10)">&lt;&lt;</button>
<button id="play" onclick="vidplay()">&gt;</button>
<button id="fastFwd" onclick="skip(10)">&gt;&gt;</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Think you need something like this:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var link = $(this).attr('href');

  BV.play();
  BV.addEvent("ended", endFunc);

  function endFunc(link) {
    window.location = link;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" preload="auto">
 <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```